# Disabling touch gestures in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, touchscreen, kiosk, gestures

I'm setting a Windows 8.1 computer with a touchscreen for a web-based betting terminal, but I'm having some problems with the gestures. Basically I'd like to disable touch gestures such as pinch-to-zoom, double-tap and press-and-hold, because they break how my site is displayed in the terminal, and they also give users a way to circumvent the webpage and open other applications. The panel uses Window's generic drivers and does not come with any kind of set up or configuration tool, such as the Synaptic Manager.

I'd love to use Linux but the touch screen panels we're using are not compatible. I guess buying new Linux-compatible panels is option if nothing works.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have a computer which also lacks those driver settings, and I long to eradicate the pinch zoom.

Comment: Is [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7vp34.png) is not what you are looking?